# Is there an on screen 'Bug Worth limit'?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

This is kind of a weird question.

I noticed while grinding on the Tropical Island that I went long bouts where all I would see was Fruit Beetles and Wharf Roach. I was ignoring them since they are only worth 200 and 100 bells each. While ignoring them not much else would show up until I actively chased them away. There was also a period of time where I didn't see much of anything new until I noticed a Horned Hercules on a tree in the back that I had not checked in a while.

For example, if I ignore too many Fruit Beetles and Wharf Roach's are other bugs going to stop showing up because there are too many bugs on the screen.

Or if a rare bug has spawned, are other bugs less likely to spawn because the valuable rare bug is taking up the allotted 'bug worth' available for the Island at the moment.

So I was wondering if anybody knows of a 'bug formula' that limits what can be on screen at any one time? Of course it could also just random and I am just seeing something that isn't there in my frustration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a bug *cost* limit, there is a bug *spawn* limit. From my own observations and from discussions on the Animal Crossing subreddit, **the Island can only spawn a maximum of 5-6 bugs at once**.

If most/all of the bugs you currently have spawned are "trash" bugs, like Fruit Beetles and Wharf Roaches, scare them away so the higher value beetles can spawn. I'm disinclined to believe that there's a "worth" limit, given that I've had Golden Stags spawn with Horned Hercules and Goliath Beetles at once before, and I've never seen any other discussion implying that there is any sort of invisible worth ceiling.

Remember that spawns are still random, so in doing a circuit around your Island, you can still end up seeing only 1-2 bugs just because of chance. Be diligent about chasing away the low value bugs (especially the Wharf Roaches, as more than one tend to spawn at once), and you should end up seeing more high value bugs.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to maximize your bug profit on the island is to cut down any tree that is not a palm tree, and remove any flowers as well. The most profitable beetles spawn off of plam trees at night, and it takes most of the low profit bugs (fruit beetles, monarch butterflies, etc.) out of the picture.

If you get Wharf Roaches, it's best to swing your net near them to clear them out to reduce the amount of bugs spawned on the island, so higher money bugs have a chance to shine.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but is there confirmation of this, I wonder? I'd like to know where you got this information before I start cutting down trees willy-nilly on my own island.

Comment: Last night I went almost exclusively with beetles on palm trees and netted about 100k in bells during one trip, with the exception of a rainbow stag and I found on a regular tree. I'd suggest keeping one regular tree to repopulate if you start missing them.